# What deal does Finch make with H.R. In "Person of Interest"?

Tags: person-of-interest

In Season 1 Episode 19 of "Person of Interest", Elias kidnaps Carter's son, so Finch goes to Officer Simmons, who is part of H.R., a group of corrupt cops who are working with Elias at the time.  The following conversation ensues.

> Finch: Look, I recognize, Officer, that I'm placing myself in danger by sitting here with you.  I need you to understand that you're placing your family in danger by doing business with Elias.
>
> Simmons: What the hell is this?
>
> Finch: The man following your wife is an ex-con whose prior convictions include rape, manslaughter Elias is keeping you and yours in check Until his plan is finished.  After that Who knows whether he'll have any use for you.
>
> Simmons: How do I know this guy doesn't work for you, huh? L
>
> Finch: I imagine you don't. But are you really willing to bet your family's life on it?
>
> Simmons: What do you want?
>
> Finch: **You need to get me the location of Detective Carter's son and call off any men you have working on Elias's behalf.  HR severs its ties with Elias as of this moment.**

And after that, H.R. does exactly what Finch asked them to do.  So my question is, why did they do what Finch wanted?  Did Finch offer them something in return?  Otherwise how would it benefit H.R. to reveal the location of Carter's son?

Did Finch somehow manage to get rid of all Elias' people who were following  the families of H.R. members?  The show doesn't make that clear.

No spoilers beyond season 1, please.

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28301/49.

Comment: I thought when Finch take care of Elias, get arrested ,  his people will be without leader and HR could  have easily took care of those people.

Comment: @Panther Well, Elias' organization wasn't affected by his arrest.  He continued to run it from jail.

Answer (score 2):

**Finch provides information and that information is already valuable enough for a deal**

I don't think there is any mystery about why HR cooperates with Finch. They didn't know that Elias was, effectively, double crossing them (or at the very least retaining a very nasty back up plan in case he needed future leverage). Finch not only knew the Elias plan but could provide specific details about the men shadowing the HR cops' families. This detailed information is enough to enable HR to neutralise the threat. And it is also enough to poison their relationship with Elias.

Nothing else needs to be explained.

But you will find major twists in these relationships and the implications for everyone in future episodes!